# Could Charles-Augustin de Coulomb measure the charge in Coulombs?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, history, physical-constants, coulombs-law

- Did [Charles-Augustin de Coulomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles-Augustin_de_Coulomb) know:

  - [Coulomb's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_constant)
  - Coulomb (as a unit)

if not then what was the first time it was measured?

Comment: Didn't Cavendish measure this? (see [this](https://archive.org/details/electricalresear00caveuoft)).

Answer (score 1):

No, Coulomb did not know the Coulomb as a unit. According to [this page](http://lamar.colostate.edu/~hillger/unit-definitions.html), the Coulomb was defined at the 9th CGPM (General Conference on Weights and Measures) conference, in 1948. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Conference_on_Weights_and_Measures#CGPM_meetings) gives the same date.

[Coulomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) could not measure charges, but he could create a charge and then halve it, quarter it, etc by letting the charge flow from one object to another identical one. That way he established that the force between 2 charges is inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them, and proportional to the product of the charges. Note that this is the same formula as Newton's law of gravity, it just uses charges instead of masses.

Comment: Did he know about his law: F = kq1q2 /r2? Or he didn't know about his law?

Comment: That is the law that says the force is proportional to the product of the charges (q1q2) and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them (r2). Note that I stuffed up my answer: I said proportional to the distance. I've fixed it now.

Comment: So did he use it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "So did he use it?". However, as I said in my answer, he did discover the law that gives the force between charged objects.

Answer (score 0):

Coulombs date back to the 1860's, and even predate CGS units.  The connection between the volt-ohm-second and mks units were made only in 1904.

Coulomb used e.s.u. based on the french ft lb s system.  The coulomb constant is a feature of choice of units, if charge is found from LMT, then the size of the coulomb constant can be set to one.